# scipy.optimize, IndexError: Invalid Index to Scalar Variable

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to implement scipy.optimmize.minimize on a multivariate scalar function using the nelder-mead method. My function definition when called in a print function works perfectly fine. When I turn on minimize it throws the IndexError.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math
import numpy as np

c_ = [1.,1.,1.]
d_ = [1.,1.,1.]
x_=[c_,d_]

def hamiltonian(x_):
    N=len(c_)
    return np.sum([(1/n**3.0)*(n-i)*i*(x_[0][(n-i)]*x_[0][i]+x_[1][(n-i)]*x_[1][i])-(1/n**3.0/alpha**2.0)*np.sum([x_[0][(n-i-j)]*x_[0][i]*x_[1][j] for j in range(0,(n-i+1))])  for n in range(1,N) for i in range(0,(n+1))])

print hamiltonian(x_) #no problem here

res = minimize(hamiltonian, x_, method='nelder-mead') #problem here
```

Comment: Check the `minimize` docs; I think it flattens the `x_` input variable.

Comment: This is the issue. I redid the code in the sum to match a flattened variable and it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `x_` is a list of lists:

```
>>> x_
[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
```

Thus replace the line `x_=[c_,d_]` with:

```
>>> x_ = c_ + d_
```

You'll also have to modify your `hamiltonian` for a `1xN` or `Nx1` list/array.

The simplest hack that I can think of is:

```
def hamiltonian(x_):
    N=len(c_)
    if type(x_[0]) == np.array:
        x_ = np.concatenate((x_[0:N], x_[N:]), axis=0)
    return np.sum([(1/n**3.0)*(n-i)*i*(x_[0][(n-i)]*x_[0][i]+x_[1][(n-i)]*x_[1][i])-(1/n**3.0/alpha**2.0)*np.sum([x_[0][(n-i-j)]*x_[0][i]*x_[1][j] for j in range(0,(n-i+1))])  for n in range(1,N) for i in range(0,(n+1))])
```

Comment: I see where you're going. I tried the code and it responded with TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in the line "return np.sum(...)"

Comment: I rewrote the sum so that all x_[1][...] terms became x_[(N+...)] which solved my problem in the minimize function. Still not sure about that TypeError though.

Comment: Oh I forgot axis=0

Comment: TypeError is telling you that a fundamental type (float) is not iterable